# use perl to print text in given commend

Tags: perl

I have a file name : printing_usage_file

```
john.smith
MarcoRibeiro
john.smith
john.smith
lial_chen14
```

and I need to output

```
Printing users:
john.smith
MarcoRibeiro
lial_chen14
```

on the screen when I use **printing_summary.pl -a printing_usage_file** commend.
what should I write in the perl script?

Comment: Please add some information, we can not know what you want. Why this order in your output ? what is the content of printing_summary.pl.... A better explanation of your problem will be useful to help you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you want to simply eliminate duplicate users. Here's one way. The only difference is that the output is not sorted in the same order it came in from the file.

It uses an external module, Getopt::Long to handle the arguments, then uses a hash to eliminate duplicates:

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $action;

GetOptions("a=s" => \$action,);

if ($action eq 'printing_usage_file'){
    print_usage_file();
}

sub print_usage_file {

    open my $file, '<', 'input.txt'
      or die "Can't open the file!: $!";

    my %user_hash;

    while (my $line = <$file>){
        chomp $line;
        $user_hash{$line} = 1;
    }

    print "\nPrinting users:\n\n";

    for my $user (keys %user_hash){
        print "$user\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./printing_summary.pl -a printing_usage_file

Printing users:

john.smith
MarcoRibeiro
lial_chen14
```

Comment: why i run the script it shows bad interpreter: no such file or directory

Comment: Probably because that's not where your perl binary is located. You'll have to fix the first line (the 'shebang' line) with the path to your perl installation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understood what you were asking, this should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my (%names,$i);
foreach (<>) { $names{$_} = ++$i if !$names{$_};}
print "Printing users:\n";
print $_ foreach sort {$names{$a} <=> $names{$b}} keys %names;
```

This displays the users in the same order they are found in the file while removing the duplicates.

Example output:

```
~/oneoffscripts $ perl -a printing_summary.pl printing_usage_file
Printing users:
john.smith
MarcoRibiero
lial_chen14
```